# How do I save the result of pi_string below into a new variable pi_flow?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Convert pi_string into float: pi_float
pi_string = float("3.1415926")
print(pi_string)
```

Comment: `pi_flow=pi_string` ?

Comment: Can you please reword the question. It makes no sense right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
pi_flow = pi_string
```

You can use the equals operator in python. Read up about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm).

Hopefully this helps!